# What is the unidentified shape in the drawing

Tags: technical-drawing, drafting, drawings

Woot!  HTTP://www.DigiPeer.de is back up and running so I am back to practicing part drawing in Inventor LT 2021.  I am looking at the following drawing titled "Pin" (according to some google translate).

[image]

In the drawing there is a flanged shape drawn at roughly the quarter mark of the smaller shaft.  However the shape is not dimensioned in anyway what so ever.

### What is this?

My best guess right now is that my German translation abilities is worse than I thought and this is actually a rivet and that would be the deformed head.  This my guess based on this drawing where there is a pin pattern that shows a similar flange shape in the 6.1 dia. hole.  I have yet to stumble on the assembly drawing in this section.

[image]

**Am I correct assuming this is a deformed shape symbol?**

Comment: As "stift" can mean pin then is that a designation for a thread and given the outer diameter the details are just assumed?

Comment: Look for a material designation. And find an assembly drawing using the part if possible.  Form (there's a shape and material completes it), Fit, Function. Seek along those lines

Comment: Scale appears to be 1:1.  Measure it.

Comment: @Abel the material designation is 3355.5.  Unfortunately I have no clue what that refers to.  I am still on the look out for the assembly drawings as I have a series of similar drawings to the lower one and I am wondering how they stack together currently.

Comment: @SolarMike  Interesting thought on the potential of thread indicator.

Comment: The 3355 might refer to another document set (like 2843)

Comment: @Abel No, the number is squarely in the material box (Werkstoff -> Material). I am currently in another drawing that is ticking me off, and in that one the Material number is St.37.11. To me there should ultimately be a spec sheet or index that will identify what the material numbers mean.